Deleing usernames from a Cisco switch with Netmiko
I have written dozens of scripts successfully with Netmiko, but have recently come across a situation I hadn't encountered before. I'm trying to remove a certain username from a list of switches. It looks like some switches prompt you for a 'yes' before deleting, and some have no prompt.
Is it possible to have multiple expects? If 'confirm' then send a 'y' but also expect a '#' and in either case continue on to saving the config?
I've tried:

using an 'expect' clause. Works when prompt comes up, but not on switches where it doesn't
doing a "show run | inc username " and checking the output. Works when username not there to skip the whole issue, but if username is there, I get the prompt/no-prompt issue.

I've seen solution similar to this situation but none seem to fit all cases.
